# java unicode value of char

Tags: java, string, compare, compareto

When I do Collection.sort(List), it will sort based on String's compareTo() logic,where it compares both the strings char by char.

```
    List<String> file1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    file1.add("1,7,zz");
    file1.add("11,2,xx");
    file1.add("331,5,yy");
    Collections.sort(file1);
```

My understanding is char means it specifies the unicode value, I want to know the unicode values of char like ,(comma) etc. How can I do it? Any url contains the numeric value of these?

Comment: Typecasting it to `int` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is char means it specifies the unicode value, I want to know the unicode values of char like ,(comma) etc

Well there's an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, which you can easily print out:

```
int value = ',';
System.out.println(value); // Prints 44
```

This is the UTF-16 code unit for the `char`. (As fge notes, a `char` in Java is a UTF-16 code unit, not a Unicode character. There are Unicode code points greater than 65535, which are represented as two UTF-16 code units.)

> Any url contains the numeric value of these?

Yes - for more information about Unicode, go to the [Unicode web site](http://unicode.org).

Comment: I don't know why it did not strike me :( Thanks. But am not able to get this chart/list from Unicode web site :(

Answer (score 1):

Uhm no, `char` is not a "unicode value" (and the word to use is Unicode *code point*).

A `char` is a code unit in the UTF-16 encoding. And it so happens that in Unicode's Basic Multilingual Plane (ie, Unicode code points ranging from U+0000 to U+FFFF, for code points defined in this range), yes, there is a 1-to-1 mapping between `char` and Unicode.

In order to know the *numeric* value of a code point you can just do:

```
System.out.println((int) myString.charAt(0));
```

But this IS NOT THE CASE for code points outside the BMP. For these, one code point translates to two chars. See [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-). And more generally, all static methods in `Character` relating to code points. There are quite a few!

This also means that `String`'s `.length()` is actually misleading, since it returns the number of chars, *not* the number of graphemes.

Demonstration with one [Unicode emoticon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aUnicode/Emoticons) (the first in that page):

```
System.out.println(new String(Character.toChars(0x1f600)).length())
```

prints `2`. Whereas:

```
final String s = new String(Character.toChars(0x1f600));
System.out.println(s.codePointCount(0, s.length());
```

prints `1`.

Comment: `length()` doesn't actually lie. The javadoc says what it returns and that is unicode code units.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis which doesn't prevent it from being misleading by name... But yes, I will edit the text to make it more clear.